# How to generate docs for my models and controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, documentation

I want to create docs for the models and controller of my application. Even for rake task, any background job. As I have thousands of lines of comments inline between the code, explanation of the all the functions actions..

I don't want docs for rails so

```
  rake doc:rails
```

is useless for me.

Usecase is internal detailed developer notes.

Comment: Irony is, I am here by searching the command of generating rails doc :) thank you very much

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using this rake task:

```
rake doc:app
```

This task is provided by [Rdoc](http://rdoc.sourceforge.net/). It also supports some markup that you can use to make things look better when formatted. You can see examples in the [documentation](http://rdoc.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html).

Comment: Awesome... Is there any third party plugins/gem available for better documentations. This one is fine but I am still love to have something better than this.

Comment: Rdoc is the standard core documentation for Rails, you could take a look at ERD for graphs or YARD http://yardoc.org/.

Comment: See "[Don’t use “click here” and other common hyperlink mistakes](https://medium.com/@heyoka/dont-use-click-here-f32f445d1021)".